# Python3 C++ Module - Exception - GIL not held

Tags: c++, python-3.x, windows, cmake, module

I have created a minimal reproduction of an issue I am having, trying to create a C++ based Python3 module. The build environment is CMake, Visual Studio Pro 2019, WinSDK 10.0.18362, Python 3.9.4. When executing:

```
python3 -c "import pymod"
```

I will get an exception in release mode with a NULL access. In debug Python, I get additional information.

My CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(pymod_minimal_repo_example)

find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)

add_library(pymod SHARED)
target_sources(pymod PRIVATE pymodmodule.cpp)
set_target_properties(pymod PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".pyd")
target_compile_options(pymod PRIVATE /Zi)
target_link_options(pymod PRIVATE /DEBUG:FULL)
target_link_libraries(pymod PRIVATE ${Python3_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(pymod PRIVATE ${Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Following this python reference: https://docs.python.org/3.9/extending/extending.html#a-simple-example I created the following:

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

static struct PyModuleDef pymodmodule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT, // m_base
    "pymod",               // m_name
    NULL,                  // m_doc
    -1,                    // m_size - submod not support must be static struct
    NULL,                  // m_methods - no functions present
    NULL,                  // m_slots - must be NULL
    NULL,                  // m_traverse - not needed
    NULL,                  // m_clear - not needed
    NULL                   // m_free - not needed
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_pymod(void) {
  return PyModule_Create(&pymodmodule);
}
```

It is a functionally void module which does nothing, but should still run. Note that having m_methods defined, produces the same failure.

When the failure occurs, the following is output to the console:

```
E:\projects\pymod\build\Debug>python -c "import pymod"
Fatal Python error: _PyInterpreterState_GET: the function must be called with the GIL held, but the GIL is released (the current Python thread state is NULL)
Python runtime state: unknown
```

WinDbg jit debugger then catches the issue. A partial call stack shows my PyInit_pymod is called and when creating the python module, it cascades to a failure:

```
0:000> k
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00 000000dc`abfed4a8 00007fff`71d51385 KERNELBASE!wil::details::DebugBreak+0x2
01 000000dc`abfed4b0 00007fff`71d511a8 python39_d!fatal_error_exit+0x15 [D:\a\1\s\Python\pylifecycle.c @ 2201] 
02 000000dc`abfed4e0 00007fff`71d4ea98 python39_d!fatal_error+0x1b8 [D:\a\1\s\Python\pylifecycle.c @ 2286] 
03 000000dc`abfed540 00007fff`71cbe730 python39_d!_Py_FatalErrorFunc+0x38 [D:\a\1\s\Python\pylifecycle.c @ 2302] 
04 000000dc`abfed580 00007fff`71aa8044 python39_d!_Py_FatalError_TstateNULL+0x10 [D:\a\1\s\Python\ceval.c @ 251] 
05 000000dc`abfed5b0 00007fff`71aa6cf2 python39_d!_PyInterpreterState_GET+0x34 [D:\a\1\s\Include\internal\pycore_pystate.h @ 105] 
06 000000dc`abfed5f0 00007fff`d0be13e7 python39_d!PyModule_Create2+0x12 [D:\a\1\s\Objects\moduleobject.c @ 168] 

>>>> 07 000000dc`abfed620 00007fff`751165dc pymod!PyInit_pymod+0x27 [E:\projects\pymod\pymodmodule.cpp @ 19]

08 000000dc`abfed660 00007fff`751167ee python39!_PyImport_LoadDynamicModuleWithSpec+0x104 [C:\A\34\s\Python\importdl.c @ 165] 
09 000000dc`abfed6d0 00007fff`75116749 python39!_imp_create_dynamic_impl+0x86 [C:\A\34\s\Python\import.c @ 2299] 
0a 000000dc`abfed700 00007fff`750cb94b python39!_imp_create_dynamic+0x39 [C:\A\34\s\Python\clinic\import.c.h @ 330] 
0b 000000dc`abfed730 00007fff`750ad500 python39!cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL+0x9b [C:\A\34\s\Objects\methodobject.c @ 426] 
0c 000000dc`abfed7a0 00007fff`750ad2ef python39!PyVectorcall_Call+0x5c [C:\A\34\s\Objects\call.c @ 248] 
0d 000000dc`abfed800 00007fff`750ad418 python39!_PyObject_Call+0x4f [C:\A\34\s\Objects\call.c @ 287] 
0e (Inline Function) --------`-------- python39!PyObject_Call+0xc [C:\A\34\s\Objects\call.c @ 293] 
0f 000000dc`abfed830 00007fff`7508c65f python39!do_call_core+0xb8 [C:\A\34\s\Python\ceval.c @ 5092] 
10 000000dc`abfed880 00007fff`75083963 python39!_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x5d6f [C:\A\34\s\Python\ceval.c @ 3581] 
11 (Inline Function) --------`-------- python39!_PyEval_EvalFrame+0x13 [C:\A\34\s\Include\internal\pycore_ceval.h @ 40] 
12 000000dc`abfedbb0 00007fff`750855a7 python39!_PyEval_EvalCode+0x2b3 [C:\A\34\s\Python\ceval.c @ 4327] 
13 000000dc`abfedc80 00007fff`7508823d python39!_PyFunction_Vectorcall+0x257 [C:\A\34\s\Objects\call.c @ 396] 
14 000000dc`abfedd80 00007fff`7508812f python39!_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x194d [C:\A\34\s\Python\ceval.c @ 3487] 
15 000000dc`abfee0b0 00007fff`750888e5 python39!_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x183f [C:\A\34\s\Python\ceval.c @ 3504] 
16 000000dc`abfee3e0 00007fff`750888e5 python39!_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x1ff5 [C:\A\34\s\Python\ceval.c @ 3518] 
17 000000dc`abfee710 00007fff`750888e5 python39!_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x1ff5 [C:\A\34\s\Python\ceval.c @ 3518] 
18 000000dc`abfeea40 00007fff`750854c4 python39!_PyEval_EvalFrameDefault+0x1ff5 [C:\A\34\s\Python\ceval.c @ 3518]
```

I cannot find any information on the console message, nor the int3. I have tried full purge and reinstall/update of Python.

Can anyone offer some direction to help, or know the cause?

Edit: Modified that PyModule_pymod function to display Pre and Post msg to console. Debug build exceptions, Release appears not to:

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_pymod(void) {
  printf("Pre-PyModule_Create\n");
  PyObject *obj = PyModule_Create(&pymodmodule);
  printf("Post-PyModule_Create\n");
  return obj;
}
```

Release:

```
E:\projects\pymod\build\Release>python -c "import pymod"
Pre-PyModule_Create
Post-PyModule_Create
```

Debug:

```
E:\projects\pymod\build\Debug>python -c "import pymod"
Pre-PyModule_Create
Fatal Python error: _PyInterpreterState_GET: the function must be called with the GIL held, but the GIL is released (the current Python thread state is NULL)
Python runtime state: unknown
```

Comment: The GIL is the "Global Interpreter Lock", which, apparently, you are required to hold prior to calling into any Python infrastructure.

Comment: The GIL lock issue would stop if I call Py_Initialize() but this is supposed to be for python embedded in C code apparently. Module examples and tutorials do not use this. When adding Py_Initialize I then get an error: SystemError: initialization of pymod did not return an extension module. PyModule_Create executes, I can inspect the PyObject* that is returned and see py_type member is set to "module". So convinced Py_Initialize is not the solution.

Comment: Got the same problem, but the exact same code (and same CmakeLists.txt) works fine on UNIX out of the box... No GIL-related problems...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into the same issue as you, and while debugging TLS structures, I noticed that Visual Studio had loaded python310.dll instead of python310_d.dll.

To make a long story short, when you define the _DEBUG macro, Python.h will use python310_d.lib, so you need to run the debug version of Python:

```
python_d -c "import pymod"
```

I was confused further by the fact that I did not have this issue while using pybind11. As it turned out, pybind11 undefines the _DEBUG macro while including Python.h, so it is always using python310.lib instead of python310_d.lib, even for debugging builds.

As I do not see an option to use the python_d interpreter in Visual Studio, I ended up using the release library for debugging builds using the following code:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && defined(_DEBUG)
#undef _DEBUG
#include <Python.h>
#define _DEBUG 1
#else
#include <Python.h>
#endif
```

As a sidenote, when you link against python310_d.dll, you will have to name your debug module pymod_d.pyd instead of pymod.pyd.

Comment: Really thanks to your answer, I‘ve suffered by that weird problem for several hours